# Expo - Handling a push notification click

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm new to React Native development. I use Expo.

Now my task is to receive push notifications. I have already written a backend that sends notifications and they actually arrive, which is very cool!

But I can’t figure out how I can implement click processing on notifications in such a way that the application, after it opens, performs some action. (For example, Linking.openUrl() or jump to a specific tab in the bottom tab navigator).

I created a development build to test this. It didn't work there.

Then I created a regular build and that didn't work either.

In my App component I wrote the following code:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
        const subscription = Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(response => {
            console.log(response.notification.request.content)
            Linking.openURL('https://facebook.com');
        })

        return () => {
            subscription.remove()
        }
    })
```

And it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

P.S. sorry for my English